# ¿Por qué mis rules no funcionan en NGINX?

Tags: nginx

Anduve colocando las **rewrites** en Nginx (default.conf), pero al probarlo en mi página web sigue igual sin ninguna regla añadida y no sé en donde estaría el problema. Soy nuevo utilizándolo, quizás me perdí de algo. **¿Alguna solución?**

```
server {
    limit_conn  ipcon  5;
    limit_req zone=reqcon burst=5 nodelay;

    client_body_timeout 7s;
    client_header_timeout 7s;

    listen       80;
    listen      443;
    server_name     domain.com;

    location / {
        root   html/liddo;
        index index.php index.html;
        limit_conn addr 10;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        root html/liddo;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
     rewrite ^/register/(|/)$ /register.php;

error_page   500 502 503 504 404 400  /;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has reiniciado el NginX?

Comment: @fredyfx sí, y no sé que ocurre. ¿Alguna solución?